# How to Change Ethereum to Other Names

Tags: parity, genesis

I used parity to deploy my private chain, I want to change "ethereum" to "abc", what should I do?

In my Genesis file, i modified a parameter called subprotocolName, but i used MetaMask to test transfer, always display "ETH"

Thanks first.

my Genesis file `demo.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "engine": {
    "authorityRound": {
      "params": {
        "stepDuration": "5",
        "validators": {
          "list": [
            "0xf848e3f82c239a50d0d800827e281bf7eaf9af7e"
          ]
        },
        "blockReward": "0x4563918244F40000"
      }
    }
  },
  "params": {
    "subprotocolName": "abc",
    "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x0400",
    "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
    "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
    "networkID": "6652",
    "chainID": "6652"
  },
  "genesis": {
    "seal": {
      "authorityRound": {
        "step": "0x0",
        "signature": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      }
    },
    "difficulty": "0x20000",
    "gasLimit": "0x1809d484"
  },
  "accounts": {
    "0xd43a23a3702C5C082b2b924AA42194CEd7bFaeAc": {
      "balance": "10000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
      "balance": "1",
      "builtin": {
        "name": "ecrecover",
        "pricing": {
          "linear": {
            "base": 3000,
            "word": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {
      "balance": "1",
      "builtin": {
        "name": "sha256",
        "pricing": {
          "linear": {
            "base": 60,
            "word": 12
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": {
      "balance": "1",
      "builtin": {
        "name": "ripemd160",
        "pricing": {
          "linear": {
            "base": 600,
            "word": 120
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": {
      "balance": "1",
      "builtin": {
        "name": "identity",
        "pricing": {
          "linear": {
            "base": 15,
            "word": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my node config file `node0.toml`:

```
[parity]
chain = "demo.json"
base_path = "parity0"

[account]

unlock = ["0xf848e3f82c239a50d0d800827e281bf7eaf9af7e"]
password = ["node.pwds"]

[network]
port = 30304
min_peers = 6
max_peers = 12
nat = "any"
id = 6652
bootnodes = []
discovery = true
warp = true
allow_ips = "all"
snapshot_peers = 0
max_pending_peers = 64
no_serve_light = false
reserved_peers="./reservedPeers.enode"
reserved_only=false

[rpc]
port = 8544
interface = "all"
cors=["chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn"]
apis = ["web3", "eth", "pubsub", "net", "parity", "parity_pubsub", "traces", "rpc", "shh", "shh_pubsub"]
hosts = ["all"]

[websockets]
port = 8180
interface = "all"
origins = ["none"]
apis = ["web3", "eth", "pubsub", "net", "parity", "parity_pubsub", "traces", "rpc", "shh", "shh_pubsub"]
hosts = ["all"]

[ipc]
disable = false
path = "$HOME/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/jsonrpc.ipc"
apis = ["web3", "eth", "pubsub", "net", "parity", "parity_pubsub", "parity_accounts", "traces", "rpc", "shh", "shh_pubsub"]

[mining]
author = "0xf848e3f82c239a50d0d800827e281bf7eaf9af7e"
engine_signer = "0xf848e3f82c239a50d0d800827e281bf7eaf9af7e"
notify_work = ["http://localhost:3001"]
force_sealing = true
reseal_on_txs = "all"
```

my parity start command

`parity-ethereum-2.1.10/target/release/parity --config ./node0.toml --jsonrpc-cors "chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn"`

Comment: Please share your Parity command line and Genesis configuration file.

Comment: @goodvibration Thank you. I appended to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your own symbol you have to configure from Metamask.

From Networks/Custom RPC/Show Advanced Options/Symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Your geth name is Abc but metamask by default makes it eth. You should change the parameters from the metamask settings